# What does this JS with && expression mean?

Tags: javascript

I can't read the `&&` part. How does that affect the result of the expression?

```
_1st == '0' ? TENS[_2nd] : TENS[_2nd] && TENS[_2nd] + '-' || ''
```

Answer (score 3):

The && is a short-circuited logical "AND" expression. It means that if the first condition is true check the second. If the first is false, stop and report that the overall expression is false.

Comment: what is the first condition in this case?

Comment: See rewritten line: https://jsfiddle.net/0jdou7vw/

Comment: oh that's the long hand of it? thank you. that makes it easier to understand for a beginner.